# PHP How to instantiate a class alias using a string

Tags: php

I know I can do this without the alias, but in this case trying to instantiate the object using an alias attempts to find a class by the alias name.  Can this not be done in PHP?

```
// Import of manager, admin, etc login PageObjects
use Page\Acceptance\Users\Login as ManagerLoginPage;
use Page\Acceptance\Admins\Login as AdminLoginPage;

...

// Login user type snippet
$alias= $userType . 'LoginPage'; // produces ManagerLoginPage
$User = new $alias($this); // tries to instantiate a class named 'ManagerLoginPage', which doesn't exist

$User->{'loginAs' . $userType}($user);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) explains:

> The ability to refer to an external fully qualified name with an alias, or importing, is an important feature of namespaces. This is similar to the ability of unix-based filesystems to create symbolic links to a file or to a directory.

And several paragraphs below:

> Importing is performed at compile-time, and so does not affect dynamic class, function or constant names.

This means that when you write:

```
use Page\Acceptance\Users\Login as ManagerLoginPage;
$page = new ManagerLoginPage();
```

PHP expands the aliases during the compilation to:

```
$page = new \Page\Acceptance\Users\Login();
```

You have to put the complete class name (including all the containing namespaces) into the variable `$alias` to make it work:

```
$alias = 'Page\Acceptance\Users\Login';
$User = new $alias($this);
```

Comment: Thanks, that make sense.  I had read the docs, but I wasn't able to put that together from them.  So I'm glad you added a quick explanation of what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$alias = $userType . 'LoginPage';
class_alias('Page\Acceptance\Users\Login', $alias);
$User = new $alias();
```